Number of Billable Actions Per User/Day
I am trying to figure out how to find the number of billable actions per day per user in our Power Automate tenant.
I have set up our company Microsoft Center of Excellence and none of the dashboards seem to track this.
How have any of you solved this issue? Just create your own flow or app to get the data?

You don’t get billed per action, happy to be proven wrong if you have the documentation.
